# Are there any graph algorithm implementations in Python that are not coupled with a particular implementation?

Tags: python, algorithm, sqlite, graph

I need some graph algorithms for a project. I could implement them from scratch, but before I do so I wanted to see if there was something out there that I could use. I've looked at [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/) and [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/). Networkx turns out to be memory inefficient for the size of the graphs I have to deal with. I think I'm using igraph incorrectly because it seems to just hang. I'll get more information on igraph if anyone's interested.

Networkx seemed promising because it is implemented in pure Python. The problem is that building the graph eats up all the memory. I have the graph in an SQLite database as an adjacency list.
So what I wanted to do was modify the code so that it can work directly with the SQLite representation instead of the networkx representation. Has anybody ever tried this successfully?

If that does not work, it goes back to the question in the title. Are there any graph implementations in Python that are reasonably decoupled from the graph representation?

Comment: My advice would be to post your issues with igraph as a separate question. Question asking for recommendation are off-topic as SO. If you want to solve specific problem describe what exactly are you trying to achieve and what have you done so far.

Comment: i haven't tried it, but as i understand it, all the pure python functions go through the 'basic' dictionaries. Not sure if this is any less work than just doing it by hand, but probably you could subclass DiGraph and override those dictionaries with objects that emulate a dictionary but actually access the SQLite database.